# Why react-router-dom doesn't provides location.key on first load?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, location, react-router-dom

I have a component screen using react-router, and I use a lot the param `location.key` to identifier my path and others things (`location.pathname` doesn't solved my problem).

But I realized that: when I first load my app, react-router doesn't has `location.key`, why is that ?
There is some configuration that allows me to change this behavior ?

I'm using `"react-router-dom": "^5.0.0"`
And adding:

```js
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

...

  // to access
  this.props.location
...

export default withRouter(MyComponent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. It because the history package behind the react router. It doesn't trigger at the first load to push or replace history.

First Load Component could be like below:

```
function firstLoadComponent({ history })
{
  history.replace(history.location, {/* state object */});

...
}
```

The above component has to trigger at least once. I also assume that the component wrapper of router component to get props. That's going to create first history entry to history array of React Router's history by manually.

You can create your own logic with the Web History API of React Router: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history